# DataGridView TextBox value conversion to decimal (with fixed point)

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, decimal

In a `TextBox` in `DataGridView` when I type in example 50.30
and then I convert it to `decimal` using:

```
decimal money = Convert.ToDecimal(dgv.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
```

it converts to 5030, not to 50.30... :(

or if it's 50 I need it to be converted to 50,0000 like the money type in sql server.

Any help?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Convert.ToDecimal(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
```

Where provider is instace of your class.